# Split semicolon values in DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to solve a python pandas problem where I have certain cells with semicolon split values. I would like to create a script where those values are automatically split.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd   
df =pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,9,3],'B':['a','b','c'],'C':[6,'2;6',4]}) #Current DataFrame 
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'A':[7,9,9,3],'B':['a','b','b','c'],'C':[6,2,6,4]})  #Dataframe to be created
```

Is there an easy method to do this?

Thank you in advance for any help

Comment: Why `[7,9,3]` became `[7,9,9,3]` in the new dataframe?

Comment: `df.assign(C=df['C'].astype(str).str.split(';')).explode("C")` , check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57122617/9840637

Answer (score 1):

Use `split()` method and `fillna()` method:

```
df['C']=df['C'].str.split(';').fillna(df['C'])
```

Finally use `explode()` method:

```
df=df.explode('C',ignore_index=True)
```

Now If you print `df` you will get your desired output:

```
    A   B   C
0   7   a   6
1   9   b   2
2   9   b   6
3   3   c   4
```